# Comparing CSV to JSON Objects within Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, csv, object

I am looking to build a basic config file using JSON. To begin with, I query a SQL database to get 3 values. These 3 values are stored in CSV, I would like to iterate through my JSON config file looking for a match. Should there be a match, I would like to pass the header and all the key pairs to a Powershell variable.

I have managed to get this working using a CSV as the config file but it seems JSON doesn't support the ".where" and I am completely stuck.

This is my JSON File. The 3 values I am comparing my SQL file are DFS, Message queue, errors. Should they match, I would like to eventually email the team assigned the 3 values.

```
    {
  "Messagequeue1": [
    {
      "dfs": "OAKHILL",
      "Messagequeue": "IMPORTSEQ",
      "errormsg": "Input in non-input field",
      "Ignore" : "false",
      "team": "ben@team.com.au",
      "teamcc": "middle-office@team.com.au",
      "escalate": "60"
    }
        ]
    ,"Messagequeue2": [
    {
      "dfs": "MQ",
      "Messagequeue": "MX",
      "errormsg": "ERRORMESS",
      "Ignore" : "false",
      "team": "middle-office@team.com.au",
      "teamcc": "",
      "escalate": "60"
    }           
        ]
}
```

Powershell Below.

```
$json = "C:\Temp\Example.json"
$MessageQueue = Get-Content -Path $json | ConvertFrom-Json 

$Param = @{
    Header = 'DFS','MessageQueue','ErrorMessage','CreatedDate','StartTime'
    Path = 'C:\temp\file.csv'
}
$SqlFile = Import-Csv @Param | Select-Object -Skip 2 | Select-Object -SkipLast 2 

$teamemails = @{}
$itsemails = @()

$MessageQueue | gm -MemberType Methods

ForEach ($sqlerror In $SqlFile){
    
    if ($Config = $MessageQueue.where({ $_.DFS -Match $sqlerror.DFS -And $_.ErrorMsg -Match $sqlerror.ErrorMessage -And $_.MessageQueue -Match $sqlerror.MessageQueue}))
    {
    
        Write-Host "Match sending to " -NoNewline
        Write-Output -InputObject $Config.Team

        foreach ($c in $config)
        {
            $c.Resend
        
            if ($teamemails[$c.Team] -eq $null) {
                $teamemails[$c.Team] = @()
            }

            $teamemails[$c.Team] += $sqlerror
        }
    }
    
    else {
        Write-host  'No Match sending to default'
        $itsemails += $sqlerror
    }
}
```

Comment: At first glance, your `$MessageQueue.where({...})` statement is incorrect, you're trying to refer to nested properties of `Messagequeue1` and `Messagequeue2`. Try this for example to see the difference: `$MessageQueue = Get-Content -Path $json | ConvertFrom-Json` => `$MessageQueue.PSObject.Properties.ForEach({$_.where({$_.Value.DFS -eq 'OAKHILL'})}).Value`

Answer (score 1):

`$MessageQueue` contains a single custom object with two properties `MessageQueue1` and `MessageQueue2` - `.Where({})` only operates meaningfully on *collections*.

You could change the condition to test `@($MessageQueue.MessageQueue1, $MessageQueue.MessageQueue2).Where({...})`, but this obviously breaks if the json file contains more properties.

You can use the hidden `psobject` memberset to enumerate the properties like this:

```
# create a flat array from the individual property values
$MessageQueue = $MessageQueue.psobject.Properties |ForEach-Object Value
```

... or use `Get-Member` to discover the property names:

```
# same as above, create a flat array from the individual property values
$MessageQueue = ($MessageQueue |Get-Member -MemberType Property) |ForEach-Object { $MessageQueue.$_ }
```